# How can I restore the Gallery system app to my Samsung Galaxy S5?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-5, system-apps, samsung-galaxy-s-5-mini

- I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S5 (mini, if that makes a difference) rooted through Odin
- I made a back-up of the Gallery app & data with Titanium Backup
- I deleted the Gallery app
- I want the Gallery app back as deleting it has been causing problems on my phone

**I have tried:**

- **restoring the app through Titanium Backup.** TB ends up getting stuck in an infinite restore loop and does not restore the app
  (although it does create a 0B entry in the app registry or whatever)
- **extracting the TB backup, copying it in the /system/app/Gallery folder, and installing it through ES File Explorer.** On
  installing, I get the error "there was a problem parsing the
  package."

I don't know what to try next and am not very knowledgeable in flashing, etc. What is the easiest, safest, and least painful way to restore my Gallery app? Is there somewhere I could re-download it?

Thank you.

Edit: When trying to install the app from the Downloads folder from ES File Explorer, it attempts to install the app but then gives "App not installed" error.

Comment: I'm assuming you never registered your Samsung or created a Samsung User Account? If you have, you should be able to download it via 'Samsung Apps', unless you deleted that, too.

Comment: I have a Samsung account but as this particular app is a system app it cannot be downloaded. I ended up flashing a ROM on my device which reset everything to default but I won't put it as an answer as it doesn't really answer the question (although it does fix the problem).